# Could not load file or assembly 'Haley.MVVM, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9b5f4902d3fea17a or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am building a WPF project

I've tried to update packages. Rebuilt, build, and clean the project. I have even tried to rewrite some views.

Here is the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Haley.MVVM, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9b5f4902d3fea17a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Here is one of my XAML files where I implemented the language:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CSGOSettinger.Views.Progresses.GraphicProgress1View"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:hm="http://schemas.hpod9.com/haley/mvvm"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Tlacitko" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="#744da9" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.75" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="nazevpostupu-kvalitagrafiky" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Bahnschrift Bold" Foreground="#181818" Background="{x:Null}"/>

    <Label Content="{hm:Lang krok1}" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Bahnschrift Bold" Foreground="#FF717171" Background="{x:Null}"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Background="#744da9" Style="{StaticResource Tlacitko}" Content="{hm:Lang pokracovat}" Height="35" Width="160" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,20,0" FontFamily="Bahnschrift" FontSize="16" Foreground="#fff">
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

I think the problem might be in the package itself

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71431862/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-haley-mvvm-version-4-0-2-0-culture-neutral-p?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Problem is not in the xaml view but with the nuget references.. Please ensure you have added all Relevant nuget references (in the main application). If you are using two projects where you have all xaml views in one project and other project merely references your xaml, then you need to add Nuget references in main app also.. Not only with Haley, but with all nuget packages this is a common thing.